# eslint max-line-per-function disable for object-shorthand

Tags: javascript, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

```
const mailParams = ({
  ToAddresses,
  CcAddresses,
  subject,
  sourceEmail,
  mailTemplate
}) => ({
  Destination: {
    ToAddresses,
    CcAddresses
  },
  Message: {
    Body: {
      Html: {
        Charset: 'UTF-8',
        Data: mailTemplate
      }
    },
    Subject: {
      Charset: 'UTF-8',
      Data: `${subject}`
    }
  },
  Source: `${sourceEmail}`
});
```

showing **Arrow function has too many lines (25). Maximum allowed is 15.eslint(max-lines-per-function)** eslint counting everything as a new line.how can we suppress **object-shorthand** and **function-paren-newline": ["error", { "minItems": 3 }]** line to be considered as one
ie: **total number of lines sholud be 5 or 2**

Comment: I think this is an excellent example of a time when disabling the rule would make more sense than anything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break your function into smaller chunks. Idea is to have functions doing 1 task only. That makes it more reusable and flexible.

```js
const getSenderDetails = (ToAddresses, CcAddresses) => ({ ToAddresses, CcAddresses });
const getMessageDetails = (subject, mailTeplate) => {
  const CharSet = 'UTF-8';
  return {
    Body: {
      Html: {
        Charset,
        Data: mailTemplate
      }
    },
    Subject: {
      Charset,
      Data: `${subject}`
    }
  }
}
const mailParams = ({
  ToAddresses,
  CcAddresses,
  subject,
  sourceEmail,
  mailTemplate
}) => ({
  Destination: getSenderDetails(ToAddresses, CcAddresses),
  message: getMessageDetail(subject, mailTemplate),
  Source: `${sourceEmail}`
});
```

Comment: **Note:** this is a restructure of code. Post that if you have any suggestion/ pointers, do share it as a comment

Comment: great.thanks. i thought of this but.it again makes millions of functions to the file..i dont want to create more unnecessary small chunks.

Comment: You can disable tslint

Comment: sorry.am using eslint.there is no ohter option in eslint configuration to make this count a 2 lines?